# Using parameters in synthesizable System-Verilog to declare widths of arbitrary constants

Tags: system-verilog

I have System Verilog design that uses parameters to define the widths of some signals.  There are a many cases where I need to assign particular constant values that are not all zeros or all ones to a signal with a parametric width.  What I would *like* to do is:

```
// W_CLK_CNT is a parameter passed into the module
logic [W_CLK_CNT-1:0] next_clk_cnt;
assign next_clk_cnt = W_CLK_CNT'h22;
```

But the simulator I am using (Cadence irun(64): 15.20-s017) gives me the following error:

```
ncvlog: *E,EXPSMC (../../../rtl/ccu.sv,196|36): expecting a semicolon (';') [9.2.2(IEEE)].
```

I know I can "just" excise the width specification and use `'h22` in the assignment in this example:

```
assign next_clk_cnt = 'h22;
```

but that doesn't work well in the actual case I have which is more convoluted and involves concatenating multiple fields.

If I know a-priori the width of the constant (6, in this example), then I could do the following:

```
assign next_clk_cnt = 6'h22;
```

But that causes the linter and synthesizer to whine about mismatched assignment widths (iirc, using `'h22` also caused lint warnings).  I could also do:

```
assign next_clk_cnt = {{(W_CLK_CNT-6){1'b0}}, 6'h22};
```

But that makes the intent of the assignment very difficult to determine and, as I noted earlier, this example is a distillation of the actual case I have.

Is there a readable way to specify `W_CLK_CNT'h22`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bitwidth cast.

```
assign next_clk_cnt = W_CLK_CNT'('h22);
```